# What are the Blizzard references made with the arcade machines on Hanamura?

Tags: overwatch

There are a fair amount of arcade machines on the Attackers side on Hanamura. What I'm curious about is, what games are they referencing and how are they tied to Blizzard games?

[image]

Comment: There are actually more machines upstairs, with a slightly different selection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arcade games in context are references to previous works.

- **Super Siege Mode 3:** The tank shown in the image is a tank from the StarCraft universe.
- **16-bit Hero**: An arcade machine that you do not show, which portrays a protagonist from the StarCraft universe, similar to Super Siege Mode 3.
- **Fighters of the Storm**: A play on words on the recent Blizzard release, [Heroes of the Storm](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/?-). Heroes of the Storm is a multiplayer online battle arena game, where players take control of various Blizzard heroes, in game play similar to Defense of the Ancients or League of Legends. The parody appears to be a fighting take of the game, and you can see the Tychus J. Findlay from StarCraft and Tyrael from Diablo, both of whom are playable characters in Heroes of the Storm.
- **ViVi's Adventure**: A possible reference to [Li Li Stormstout](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Li_Li_Stormstout), a Panderan from the WarCraft series.
- **The Lost Vikings IV**: A reference to [The Lost Vikings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Vikings), which is a much older game released by Blizzard, who at the time were known as Silicon & Synapse.

Comment: This is neat! OW is my first Blizzard game so it's kinda cool to see all the hidden references they put in the game.

Comment: @O-O, I seriously recommend checking out their other games. Blizzard are, in my opinion, the single best developing team for story and immersion. They have three main universes (StarCraft, Diablo, WarCraft), so if you are unfamiliar, I would start by looking up some intro videos to some of their games on YouTube.

Comment: There's also Fighters of the Storm II in at least one map, which showcases Garrosh and Kerrigan instead.

Comment: Lost Vikings 6 is also a reference to the arcade machine in the Terran campaign in StarCraft 2, which played on its namesake by instead being about a lost Viking -- a Terran air unit rather than a Norseman -- blasting its way through waves of enemies, Galaga-style.

Comment: Fighters of the Storm sounds awesome! When does it come out?

Comment: super siege mode also seems to portray a starcraft marine.